# Attempting to add xml dynamically in android with inflater

Tags: android, android-xml, android-inflate

I have my main page xml which I want to load a button into if a user does not have something in their database.

My main page xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:padding="5dip"
        >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"/>



    <TableLayout  

    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"  
    android:stretchColumns="*"> 

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableStatTitles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abvTitle"
            android:text="ABV"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/IBUTitle"
            android:text="IBU"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/glassTitle"
            android:text="Glass"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>


        </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableStat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abv"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/IBU"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/glass"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></TextView>


        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout> 







    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBrewery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text=""
        android:onClick="viewBrewery"
        />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text=""
        android:onClick="viewStyle"

        />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerDescriptionTitle"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Description:"
        android:padding="5dip"
        ></TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="5dip"

        ></TextView>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/addBeerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The xml butt I want to add is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Beer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am attempting to inflate the one xml file into the main one with:

```
//inflate with add beer button
                Inflater inflater;
                LinearLayout addButton = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.addBeerLayout);
                addButton.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.addbeerbutton_layout, null));
```

My findviewbyid give this error in eclipse:

```
    The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type CheckBeerJSON
and my inflate give this error in eclipse:
The method inflate(byte[]) in the type Inflater is not applicable for the arguments (int, null)
```

Comment: does it crash with NullPointerException?

Comment: I added the two errors I am getting to my main post

Comment: for the first error you need a context, for the second the correct class is LayoutInflater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form your comments `CheckBeerJSON` is Aynstask. So you need the context as suggested by blackbelt. Pass the activity context to the constructor of the asynctask.

From your activity class

```
     new CheckBeerJSON(ActivityName.this).execute(params);
```

Then in the constructor of asynctask.

```
     Context mContext;
     public CheckBeerJSON(Context context)
     {
       mContext = context;
     }
```

To infalte a layout you need `LayoutInflater`.

```
   LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Also

```
   LinearLayout addButton = (LinearLayout)((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.addBeerLayout);
   addButton.addView(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.addbeerbutton_layout, null));
```

Also make sure you do not update ui in `doInbackground`.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! I should be able to figure out the rest from here!

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a computer here, so I cannot post an example, but maybe a hint is enough.

viewstub could be a good choice, if I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this in my apps is as follows.

```
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

//Layout defined in XML
LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)
    findViewById(R.id.layout);

//View to add to XML layout
View mView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view,
    mLinearLayout, false);

mLinearLayout.addView(mView);
```

Comment: layout_inflater_service gives me this error:

LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: That is strange, I have this exact code in my Eclipse screen right now and I don't see any errors. Maybe try (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE). Your error might be elsewhere, can you post the rest of the code where this is used?

Comment: @Mike is your `checkBeerJSON` extend activity or not.

Comment: It extends AsyncTask, as it is calling an external api to see if the user has a beer in their portfolio or not. If they dont then this button should appear.

Comment: LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE is a member of Context ... try `Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE` instead, you might need an actual instace of it though.